# unable to set Thread for current user while running controller rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, thread-safety

We have written after_create callback where we use Thread.current[:current_user_id]
but While running controller rspec spec fail because of  Thread.current[:current_user_id] got as nil.

Comment: Please elaborate: What does your model, the controller and our spec look like? What is the exact error message?

Comment: While executing rspec we create record for specific model. Then after create callback calls. in same callback we create one history record for this we are using Thread.current[:current_user_id]. becuase of getting Thread.current[:current_user_id] nil rollback model transaction and rspec fails.

Comment: Why not use the PaperTrail gem to create the history for you?